# Hotspot not working after upgrading from 16.10 to 17.04

Tags: 17.04, hot-spot

[image]

I am using `kde5-mn-connection` manager for creating wifi hotspot since none of the default Ubuntu methods works for me.

Recently I upgraded to 17.04 from 16.10 using usb start-up disk

After that when I try to turn on my wifi hotspot the following is displayed

> Failed to activate connection

Comment: Are you trying to create a hot spot or connect to one you created yourself (with Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble **creating** hotspot, then do this.
Type this in your command line:

`sudo apt install hostapd dnsmasq`

Then try creating hotspot again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I myself found an answer

Install ap-hotspot

Find it in this link
https://pkgs.org/download/ap-hotspot

and install it through Gdebi Package installer

Go to Terminal By typing At+ Cntrl + T

Type "sudo ap-hotspot start"

You are done